# How can you see what is making changes to an SQL Server database?

Tags: sql-server, triggers, wiki

I am looking for the best way to figure out what program, stored procedure or user is making changes to an SQL Server database.

Comment: Why tag this Wiki? I doesn't seem to relate to Wiki at all.

Answer (score -1):

I managed to solve this by using SQL triggers *(This might also be achievable with [SQL Server Audit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/auditing/sql-server-audit-database-engine).)*

This tool is most useful for finding the source of a change to a table (dll, stored procedure, etc). SQL Profiler has very limited functionality in regards to this so the best way to get this information is to create a trigger and log the information to a table.

STEPS:

1. Create a table in which to store the results of your trigger
2. Create a trigger that logs the event that causes the change
3. Create a scheduled job that cleans old records so as to keep table size low
4. Cleanup everything once you have finished investigating the issue

​​
Note: You might have to change the user of the job in order for it to have permission to run.

```
--1. SQL Server log table
USE MySQLDatabase; --Search and replace all cases of the database name before use
CREATE TABLE SQLLog 
(
    language_event NVARCHAR(100),
    parameters INT,
    event_info NVARCHAR(4000),
    event_time DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);
GO
 
--2. Trigger to monitor Session Update
CREATE TRIGGER LogMySQL
ON tblName --Trigger will be placed on this table
AFTER UPDATE--, INSERT, DELETE --(you can add records if you also want to see insert or deletes happening)
AS 
     INSERT INTO SQLLog (language_event, parameters, event_info)
        EXEC('DBCC INPUTBUFFER(@@SPID);');
GO
 
--3. Job that clears all records from the table that are more than 7 days old
USE msdb;
GO
EXEC dbo.sp_add_job
    @job_name = N'Run SQLLogClean' ;
GO
EXEC sp_add_jobstep
    @job_name = N'Run SQLLogClean',
    @step_name = N'Delete all old records from SQLLogClean',
    @subsystem = N'TSQL',
    --@command is the query that will get executed by the job. 7 is the age in days of rows you want to delete
    @command = N'USE MySQLDatabase delete from SQLLog where event_time < (getdate() - 7)',
    @retry_attempts = 5,
    @retry_interval = 5 ;
GO
--Schedule to run daily at 04:00
EXEC dbo.sp_add_schedule
    @schedule_name = N'RunDaily',
    @freq_type = 4, -- Value of 4 means Daily
    @freq_interval = 4,
    @active_start_time = 040000 ; --Start time for job. Format is HHMMSS
GO
EXEC sp_attach_schedule
   @job_name = N'Run SQLLogClean',
   @schedule_name = N'RunDaily';
GO
EXEC dbo.sp_add_jobserver
    @job_name = N'Run SQLLogClean';
GO
 
--4. Cleanup once all has finished
/*
USE msdb;
IF EXISTS (SELECT job_id FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobs_view WHERE name = N'Run SQLLogClean')
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_delete_job @job_name=N'Run SQLLogClean', @delete_unused_schedule=1
GO

USE MySQLDatabase;
DROP TABLE SQLLog;
DROP TRIGGER LogMySQL;
*/
```

[Source](http://pratchev.blogspot.co.nz/2008/04/auditing-data-modification-statements.html)

Comment: Have you ever worked with large havealy used databases?

Comment: This should be used primarily as a diagnostic tool, it was not designed with prolonged use in mind. However as you can specify which table it is to run on and also what kind of statements cause it to log it is unlikely you will cause a large overhead if you use it strategically.